# Increment strings like '20px'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need something to increment string values representing length (css margins)

the current solution is:

```
function incPx(a,b){
     return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) +'px';
}
incPx($(el).css('margin-left'), '10px')
```

but there may be a jQuery thing for that maybe? to work with other units that 'px'

Comment: I edited the title: strings -> css values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have already suggested `jQuery.css()`'s relative values, but keep in mind that you can easily use `parseInt` to convert a string like `50px` to a `Number`, like so:

```js
console.log(parseInt('50px', 10));
// 50
```

```js
function incPx(a, b){
    a = parseInt(a, 10) || 0;
    b = parseInt(b, 10) || 0;
    return (a + b) +'px';
}​
```

Don't forget to pass a `radix` of 10, though. More examples: [Example: Using parseInt (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseInt#Example%3a_Using_parseInt)

Comment: a great I edited the Q with that useful tip, but  .css("margin-left", "+=10px") is exactly what I need

Comment: @cyril: I thought so. Don't forget the `radix`, though! If you don't, JavaScript might choose one for you (e.g. `8` or `16`). For example, `08px` would become `10`, because JS defaults to `radix` `8` when the string starts with a `0`...

Comment: Your sample code is essentially the same as the OP's question code, with the addition of a radix :)

Comment: @Chris: yes, but so is yours, isn't it?

Comment: @PPvG Yes, mine is too :) There's no free-lunch way to increment "auto", you'd have to measure the element first... I'm not going there for this one!

Comment: `parseInt()` is very useful in this case. Thanks for reminding it to us! +1

Answer (score 6):

With jQuery 1.6+, you can pass relative amounts to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), indicated by `+=` or `-=`, similar to `.animate()`:

```
$(el).css('margin-left', '+=10px');
```

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.6, `.css()` accepts relative values similar to `.animate()`. Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, `.css( "padding-left", "+=15" )` would result in a total padding-left of 25px.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here, discussing the "jQuery way", are perfectly valid. However, I wanted to include a method that uses an approach similar to the one that the OP is using, which could be used with "vanilla" javascript too.

Note that the OP's code would, as it stands, work just fine -- this is basically the same thing with a little more care paid to giving defaults

```
function incPx (val, amt) {
    var nv = parseInt(val.replace(/[^0-9]/, ''), 10);
    return (
        (nv ? nv : 0) + (amt || 1)
    )+'px';
};

console.log(incPx('10px')); // 11px
console.log(incPx('let us hasten to the zoo, post haste!')); // 1px
console.log(incPx('10px', 10)); // 20px
console.log(incPx('10px', -2)); // 8px
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/jxU6Q/2/

**Documentation**

- `parseInt` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
- `String.replace` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: it's probably what jquery is doing too

Comment: @cyril Agreed, something similar. I prefer to use as much vanilla code as possible, though, because I like to avoid js libraries as much as possible. You've gotten some good jQuery-specific answers here, I wanted to add a plain JS answer just for posterity's sake -- I assume you'll use a jQuery-based solution.